# How to use PAUSE in a Start > Run command

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How can I keep the cmd window from closing when running a command from Start > Run? The window always closes immediately using the following command. The `PAUSE` is always ignored.

```
"%SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe" & PAUSE
```

Comment: What is your ultimate goal?  are you trying to tell someone what their User name is or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
cmd /C whoami & pause
```

Comment: Using the syntax you provided.. specifically `cmd.exe /c "%SystemRoot%\System32\whoami.exe" & PAUSE`.. but David is right.

Comment: Ok. I will give you this one. I will ask another question about using `NET USER`.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command:

```
cmd /k whoami
```

This will start command prompt.
/k says to use a window and keep it open
and whoami is the command you actually want to run. If your command has spaces, put the entire command in quotes. For example:

```
cmd /k "echo keep the window open"
```

Do note, the other answers and your question use the PAUSE command, which means, after you press a key, the window closes. This solution will allow you to interact with the window after running the command, such as scrolling, entering more commands, etc.. Type exit or press the close button when done.

Comment: He was asking how to pause (as in with /c), not keep the window open forever.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas he asks: "How can I keep the cmd window from closing when running a command", which this does. Maybe he prefers my solution. Maybe someone else finds this question and prefers this solution. If it helps anyone, me posting this answer was a good thing.